# Adding empty element to declared container without declaring type of element

Tags: c++, c++11

When we use a complicated container in C++, like

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>> table;
```

The only way to add an empty map (which may represent a row or column) is to initialize a new element and push it back. For example with

```
table.push_back(std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>());
```

Is there any way to avoid redeclaring the type, and just adding the correct typed element?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From CLion's IntelliSense, I later found that one useful method is `emplace_back()`. This constructs a new object of correct type and adds it to the end of the vector.

```
table.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 25):

You can take advantage of [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11) and  just write

```
table.push_back({});
```

Answer (score 11):

Before C++11 sometimes I use `x.resize(x.size()+1)`, in C++11 or later you can use `x.push_back({})`.

Answer (score 5):

Though the other answers are correct, I will add that *if* you couldn't take that approach, you could have benefitted from declaring some type aliases to shorten that container type name.

I can of course only guess at the logical meaning of your containers, which is another thing that this fixes!

```
 using PhilosopherNameType = std::string;
 using NeighboursType      = std::set<PhilosopherNameType>;
 using NeighbourMapType    = std::map<PhilosopherNameType, NeighboursType>;

 std::vector<NeighbourMapType> table;
 table.push_back(NeighbourMapType());
```

I mention this because you can likely still benefit from this in other places.

Comment: agreed. Along the same lines are the types that the STL gives you (vector::value_type iirc)

Comment: Is there a practical difference between using "using .... = ..." and a typedef?